# Is it allowed to fetch pictures with users permission?

Tags: rules, facebook-oauth

I'm build an image site right now, and I have of course implemented Facebook login to make everything convenient for the user.

My plan was to build a function where a user could go in and look at the pictures they have on Facebook, and click on the one the want, and then my script would use CURL to get the image and upload it to my server.

Is that allowed ? They of course have the possibility to delete the images afterwards if they don't want it there anymore.

Comment: Please consult an attorney for legal questions like this as free advice from public forums generally won't do you much good in a court of law.